# Autowired RibbonAware RestTemplate with Interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am having a wrapper that autowire ribbon aware RestTemplate and then I add a interceptor-

```
@Component
public class MyRestTemplate {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new 
        MyRestTemplateRequestInterceptor(applicationName)));
    }   
}
```

If I @AutoWire RestTemplate in some other component, will I get same instance of RestTemplate with this incterceptor? My observation is the autowired resttemplate in other component also adds this interceptor. Please help to validate the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yyou will get the same instance of RestTemplate. When the bean MyRestTemplate is constructor (rather after it's construction), you are adding the MyRestTemplateRequestInterceptor to the `RestTemplate` interceptor.
So this interceptor will be applied to `RestTemplate`.
If you are looking to apply an interceptor for a specific feign client you can create your own configuration:

```
@Configuration
@IgnoreDuringScan
public class FeignClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new GsonEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder feignDecoder() {
       return new GsonDecoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestHeaderInterceptor() {
        return new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
                //impl
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Feign.Builder feingBuilder() {
        return Feign.builder().encoder(feignEncoder()).decoder(feignDecoder()).errorDecoder(new YourErrorDecoder())
            .requestInterceptor(requestHeaderInterceptor);
    }

}
```

Then just apply the configuration to your feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "myFeign", url = "url/...", configuration = {
 FeignClientConfiguration.class
})
public interface YourFeignClient {
    //....
}
```